# how to filter one property by another property from same list - react js

Tags: javascript

**I have a list like this:**

```
let conlocations = [{
  mruCode: "1700",
  division: "Agricultural",
  country: "USA",
  currency: "USD",
  ...
}, {
  mruCode: "1000",
  division: "Agricultural",
  country: "CANADA",
  currency: "CAD",
  ...
}, {
  mruCode: "1500",
  division: "Industrial",
  country: "AUSTRALIA",
  currency: "AUD",
  ...
}]
```

Now i have dropdownlist having these items and i have one label which will show the currency based on selection of dropdown.

suppose in dropdownlist Items are - 1700,1000,1500(mruCode). Based on these selection currency will show in label.

Now i have created a reducer to filter out currency and created a new list to save them. I put these as an onChange event. Problem is initially label is showing blank because new list is empty.

reducer code:

```
case 'CURRENCY_LIST':
        let newState = Object.assign({}, state)
        let newCurrList = newState.conLocations.filter((el) => el.mruCode === action.payload)
        return Object.assign({}, newState, {
            currList: newCurrList
        });
```

Initially currList is empty. How to filter out same list one property by another.